# Versioning a RESTful API with both XML and JSON Content-Type

Tags: json, rest, content-type, http-1.1, hateoas

According to [this excellent presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/u/dzuelke/p/designing-http-interfaces-and-restful-web-services-sfliveparis2012-2012-06-08) on designing RESTful interfaces, the preferred way to implement versioning is to utilize the Accept-header, using something like:

```
GET /products HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/vnd.com.myservice.v2+xml
```

This works perfectly for XML Content-Types, but **is possible to use the same scheme for versioning the JSON-equivalent**?

I.e, is it possible to ask for:

```
GET /products HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/vnd.com.myservice.v2+json
```

The response would be something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.com.myservice.v2+xml; charset=UTF-8
Allow: GET, POST

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products xmlns="urn:com.example.products" 
          xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <product id="1234" xl:type="simple" 
           xl:href="http://example.com/products/1234">
    <name>Red Stapler</name>
    <price currency="EUR">3.14</price>
    <availability>false</availability>
  </product>
</products>
```

and the JSON equivalent (sort of):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.com.myservice.v2+json; charset=UTF-8
Allow: GET, POST

[
  {
    id: "1234",
    links: [
      {
        rel: "self",
        href: "http://example.com/products/1234"
      }
    ],
    name: "Red Stapler",
    price: {
      currency: "EUR",
      value: 3.14
    },
    availability: false
  }
]
```

Comment: +1 for the link to that presentation if nothing else. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can implement versioning either by adding a version in the **content type**:

```
application/vnd.acme.user-v1+xml
```

Or you can also use a qualifier in your `Accept` header, that way you don’t touch your content type:

```
application/vnd.acme.user+xml;v=1
```

You can split your content type `application/vnd.acme.user+xml` in two parts: the first one (`application/vnd.acme.user`) describes the media type, and the second one (`xml`) the format of the response. That means you can use another format like `json`: `application/vnd.acme.user+json`.

In the HATEOAS world, XML is better than JSON for readability and semantic purposes, if you want to use JSON, you could be interested by this specification: https://github.com/kevinswiber/siren.

Comment: Thanks. When it comes to deciding between a qualifier and a new media type, which one would you prefer for versioning and why?

Comment: I would use the qualifier to avoid modifying the content type. It's just a matter of taste I guess.

Answer (score 5):

The cleanest way I know is by using profiles. There is an IETF RFC for that ([RFC 6381](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6381.txt)).

Using the accept header, indicate what type of response you expect. You can still use qualifiers as well. You can request compliance with one or more comma-separated profiles, but you must use quotes if you specify more than one profile.

**Accept:** application/json; profiles="http://profiles.acme.com/user/v/1"

Using the content-type header, the server can respond alike:

**Content-Type:** application/json; profiles="http://profiles.acme.com/user/v/1"